# Issue: Control Span Using Table Layout Panel Column AutoSize

Tags: vb.net, winforms, show-hide, tablelayoutpanel, autosize

### Goal

I need to have a control *TextBox* (Column: 2) that is stored inside a TableLayoutPanel to hide and show with the checking/unchecking of a checkbox. During this hide and show, its column must completely collapse when hidden. A *Label* control needs to be spanning through the table layout panel's columns. So when the *TextBox* is hidden, the 2nd column must completely collapse because the 3rd column is set to percentage (100%).

- Note: I place all my controls in a table layout panel to correctly size the forms between different users' display (100%, 125%, 150%).

See below:

**Control: Label - Not spanning**
[image]

**Control: Label - Spanning 3 columns**
[image]

---

I would think that the 2nd column should collapse due to the *TextBox* not being visible anymore and the 2nd column' sizing property being set to autosize.

Keep in mind this is a clearer example of what I'm trying to replicate in my actual program. I figured it was simpler to display it this way. I actually need to have the feature expand and collapse the column correctly.

Am I omitting something important? It is very odd that the 2nd column actually gets larger

Answer (score 0):

This is working on my end. I don't know if it's because I put the Label on the Form opposed to the TableLayoutPanel. If you haven't tried that, I suggest you do.

Make sure the Label is not in the TableLayoutPanel in the Document Outline (Ctrl+Alt+T).

[image]

Here are my control properties in the designer file

Label. Anchor property was changed

```
Me.Label1.Anchor = CType(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) _
    Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right), System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
Me.Label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 32)
Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(338, 18)
Me.Label1.TabIndex = 0
Me.Label1.Text = "Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test T" & _
"est Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test"
```

TableLayoutPanel. Dock property was changed as well as columns and rows.

```
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.OutsetDouble
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 3
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle())
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle())
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100.0!))
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.CheckBox1, 0, 0)
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox1, 1, 0)
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Name = "TableLayoutPanel1"
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 26.0!))
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle())
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(344, 233)
Me.TableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 1
```

The CheckBox and TextBox are nothing special.

The CheckBox checked handler is simply

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    Me.TextBox1.Visible = Me.CheckBox1.Checked
End Sub
```

And this is what my form does when checked and unchecked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm, well this is a sort of patch to the problem but I still don't understand why the TableLayoutPanel reacts as such. I use table layout panels for the users who have different display percentages (100%,125%,150%).

What is interesting is if we were to do the same logic as the show/hide for a row, it works... But not with a column

Comment: What patched it, the fact that the Label needed to be outside of the TLP?

Comment: Yes, that's not exactly a fix. The label must reside in that particular cell for ease of use. However, the fact that the column gets larger when the control is invisible is odd to me since the last column is a percentage. Still, I thank you for the effort in your help!!

Comment: "The label must reside in that particular cell for ease of use." whose ease, the developer's or the user's? From the user's perspective, it seems to be working fine. For the developer, you could wrap it all in a usercontrol, maybe even derive a control from TableLayoutPanel. A lot of ways to make it work.